# Apache ProxyPass and Node.js - not serving up socket.io

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io, proxypass

I'm trying to run a Node.js alongside my existing apache and I have a ProxyPass problem when serving content from my Express.js server. What's seems to be the trouble is the request that the Node server sees when it is forwarded by Apache.

I tried this config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /node http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Node is setup the server like such:

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, server = require('http').createServer(app)
, io = require("socket.io").listen(server) 

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.method, req.url); // log the method and route
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/components', express.static(__dirname + '/components'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
```

I get this logged by node:

```
GET /
GET //components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
GET //components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
GET //css/flags.css
GET //css/app.css
GET //components/jquery/dist/jquery.js
GET //components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
GET //socket.io/socket.io.js
GET //js/client.js
GET //components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map
```

**Question: I am getting an extra slash when apache sends the request and the socket.io library is not served. How can I make Apache remove leading slashes before they get to node.js?**

Comment: On a related note, if you're using something like socket.io, you're going to be better off using something like nginx in front of node and apache (even if you're using the event mpm) instead, especially if you are going to be doing any kind of scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with HAProxy to sit in front of node and apache; as suggested in the comments above.

These are the settings I went with:

```
 frontend main
    bind *:80
    mode http
    default_backend apache

    acl is_node path_beg -i /node/
    use_backend node if is_node

    acl is_node_too path_beg -i /node
    use_backend node if is_node_too

    acl is_socket path_beg -i /socket.io/
    use_backend socketio if is_socket

    acl is_socketio_too path_beg -i /socket.io
    use_backend socketio if is_socketio_too

backend apache
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    server      apache localhost:81

backend node
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    server      node localhost:3000
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /node/(.*)     \1\ /\2
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /node(.*)     \1\ /\2

backend socketio
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    server      node localhost:3000
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /node/(.*)     \1\ /\2
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /node(.*)     \1\ /\2
```